# Keeping angular synced with database

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I started to learn angular.js and i am buidling my own todo application. The app has tasks and task groups. Now when i create a new group i use the following to immediately show me the newly added group;

```
$scope.groupModel.push(item);
```

Also i send the following post to update the database

```
$http.post(absUrl + "/Task/CreateGroup", item);
```

The group is created in the database and a new unique key is generated automatically (SQL Server primary key with index).

Now i would like to add a task to this group, angular allows me to add a new task, but it does not know which unique group key was created in the database. So when i save the new task the group key is empty.

I could offcourse do a get request after group creation to retreive the groups again including the new unique key, but this slows down the process and i would like to keep the ui responsive.

I believe there to be a simple solution for keeping the front and back-end in check without waiting on get refreshes, although i am unsure what this would be.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't return the unique key from the post?

Comment: I do not know how, what is the syntax for returning the key in asp and catching this returned key in angular?